# Export from database to Excel MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm new to mvc and c# and I've been struggling with export from db to Excel. In the view I have a table and a button Export which calls the function from the Home Controller:

```
<button type="submit" id="export" onclick="Export()">Export to Excel</button>
    <script>
        function Export() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/ExportToExcel",
                success: function(data) { },
                error: function() {
                    ErrorMessage("Error occurred");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

and this is the function from the Home Controller:

```
public void ExportToExcel()
{
    var y = (from w in db.OrderProducts
             group w by w.IdOrder into TotaledOrder
             select new OrderP
             {
                 IdOrder = TotaledOrder.Key,
                 price = TotaledOrder.Sum(s => s.price)
             }).ToList();

    var result = (from o in db.Orders
                  join h in db.Clients on o.IdClient equals h.IdClient
                  select new OrderRep
                  {
                      IDOrder = o.IdOrder,
                      Data = o.Date,
                      Sum = 0,
                      Name = h.name,
                      Adress = h.adresa
                  }).ToList();

    foreach (var order in result)
    {
        order.Sum = y.Where(q => q.IdOrder == order.IDOrder).Sum(q => q.price);
    }

    string filename = "Orders.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
    DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
    dgGrid.DataSource = result;
    dgGrid.DataBind();

    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");

    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

I have no errors but the Excel file is not created when I click on the button. If you could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please use Chrome Developer Tools to show us the request and response headers for this specific http request.

Comment: If the table in your view already contains the info that you want to export to excel, then I would look into using [jQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/).  They provide functionality to [export to excel](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't download files via AJAX - the received data ends up in a JavaScript variable inside the page, instead of in a file on the user's disk.

You need to use a regular HTTP request. A hyperlink which opens in a new window would do the job (instead of your button):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Home")" target="_blank">Export to Excel</a>
```

---

N.B. It's worth also pointing out that your action method actually creates a HTML string and then sends it for download with a ".xls" extension to give the impression that it's an Excel file when it isn't. Excel can certainly open and read HTML documents, but it isn't truly an Excel file, you can't do all the things with it that can be done with a native Excel file. Your data would probably display just as well in a web browser.